# What is missing in my reddit Acces Token?

Tags: api, curl, reddit

I'm using the following Curl command to get the access token :

```
curl -X POST  -A 'Pandora:PandoraBI' -d 'grant_type=password&username=BI_Repoting&password=MYPASS' --user 'uooyAT5t0yCZjg:MYCLIENTSECRET' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

and it shows the following error:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}hperea@es-etl-stage-01:~$
```

Comment: it's working for me, maybe a typo in username/password ?

Comment: previous to get the access token, you make the authorization?

Comment: I mean in "username=BI_Repoting&password=MYPASS"